# The pronunciation of the Japanese translation of dictionary

Tags: pronunciation

the pronunciation of 辞書 is jisho, however, why does it sound like jishyo in prerecorded pronunciation online?

Comment: `prerecorded pronunciation online` -- Which one? Could you give us the link?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure of the recording you are referring to, but just looking at jisho.org, the entry sounds like "jisho" to me. [https://jisho.org/word/辞書](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8) -- so it isn't a universal phenomenon!

One possible reason as to why your resource is saying "jisyo" is that one of the major systems of romanisation of Japanese (the Nihon-shiki system; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon-shiki_romanization) uses 'syo' instead of 'sho' (as represented in the Hepburn system) to represent しょ. A computer-generated rendering of 'syo' might therefore just sound as such.